# Перенос последнего слова вместе с :after иконкой

Tags: css

Задаю иконку справа от div-а с текстом через псевдоэлемент:

```
div:after {
    content: "";
    background-image: url(img.svg);
    margin-left: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
}
```

Как сделать, чтобы она переносилась на следующую строку вместе с последним словом, а не по отдельности – сначала иконка, потом текст.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я ничего лучше не придумал:

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid;
  animation: w-7-12 2.5s linear infinite alternate;
}

span {
  white-space: nowrap;
}

span:before {
  content: "\A0";
}

span:after {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  background: red;
  width: .75em;
  height: .75em;
}

@keyframes w-7-12 {
  from { width: 7ch; }
  to { width: 12ch; }
}
```

```html
<div>12345 789<span></span></div>
```

PS: Проверял только в хроме, но по идее должно работать.

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял вопрос, то нужно задать позиционирование, вот пример:
- родитель обязательно должен иметь также позиционирование
- блок `after` уже абсолютно него

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: relative;
  width: 50vw;
  padding: 1rem;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
  background-color: #fff;
}

div:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -20px;
  right: -20px;
  z-index: -1;
  background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/40);
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div>Некий текст</div>
```

Comment: Неправильно понял...